# admob linear layout double ads?

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I want to add admob to my program but it always shows two ads instead of one. I want to ad to be on top center of my activity . These two ads are stick toghether on top how can I remove one of them ?

here is the xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:gravity="top"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_switch_on" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/Develop"
    android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/soheilen"
    android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:minHeight="64dp"
    android:minWidth="64dp"
    android:src="@drawable/more" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/mute"
    android:textOff="@string/mute"
    android:textOn="@string/mute" />







    <LinearLayout 

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainline" 
        android:gravity="top"
        >

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="aXXXXXXXXXXb"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:gravity="top" >
   </com.google.ads.AdView>     

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my codes in main java :

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,"xxxxxxxxxxxx");


    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainline);

    layout.addView(adView);

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I tried other settings like to relative layouts but its not working properly !

Comment: Why are you adding two AdView, one in xml and other programmatically, delete either of one.

Comment: @Oam im new to android which one is better to remove and if i remove in xml how align the one in the codes ?

Comment: Remove your third and fifth lines in the above code and try checking it.

Comment: worked like charm tnx

Comment: type the answer so i can chose ur answer as final answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works good, except you added the `AdView` in code and in xml. You can delete either of one and implement it.

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();           
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Happy coding:)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"`, you dont need to add any code in your Java file.
I think it will cause ad request to be made two times which can increase your requests unexpectedly.
Remove the Ad request code in your Java file and just keep the XML code.  Link:-[link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals)